# how to pass generated token in header in python flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a login API that will generate a token I want take that token as request and I want to call another API using that below is my python script could you please help me to get.
below is the login request with post method I am hard coding the credentials I want to login with these credentials after successfully logged IN it will generate a token. Using that token Want to call another API called prospects

```
import requests

url = "http://website/login"
payload="{\"username\": \"abc@test.com\", \"password\": \"password\"}\r\n"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
token1 = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
p1 = "http://website/prospect"
headers = {
  # 'Authorization': token1,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
api_call_response = requests.get(p1, headers={'Authorization': token1})
print(api_call_response.text)
```

on the first post request I am able to generate the token on the second call I want to take the token and call the prospect I am not able to call another API could you please help me to get that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requests.request returns a response object. you can get the response text this way:

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
token1 = response.text
print(token1)
```

assuming that the response is something like this:

```
{"token": "f8DigrXubwYQj1KbUS0M9mOTNlHUKG"}
```

then you can use it this way:

```
respons_object = response.json()
p1 = "http://website/prospect"
api_call_response = requests.get(p1, headers={'Authorization': respons_object['token']})
```

in [Requests User Guide](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/#requests-http-for-humans) you can find good tips and hints.

besides that, there are different types of tokens. Bearer, JWT, etc. you may need to add the token type to your header. like this:

```
headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(respons_object['token'])}
```

Comment: This works for me Thanks for your help 
api_call_response = requests.get(p1, headers={'Authorization' : f'Bearer {respons_object["token"]}'})

Comment: I will add this to my answer. happy to see that your problem solved